# Why we cannot dynamically allocate a pointer to a function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, malloc

I tried to dynamically allocate a pointer to a function like that

```
void (*f)(void*);
f = (*f)malloc(sizeof(f) * 2);
```

and I got an error.

> error: expected ';' before 'malloc'

After I searched, I discovered that we cannot dynamically allocate a pointer to a function, we can only declare it like an array. In first step, I declare it an array of functions

```
void (f[2])(void*);
```

and I saw that I got an another error, that I cannot declare an array of functions, I must declare it an array of pointers to functions.

```
void (*f[2])(void*);
```

In my search I discovered too, that a  pointer to a function doesn't point to data, it points to code.
If someone can explain me why we cannot dynamically allocate a pointer to a function and why we cannot have a array of function instead of array of pointers to functions.

My code is following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printNr(void *nr)
{
    printf("%i\n", nr);
}

void printChar(void *ch)
{
    printf("%c\n", ch);
}

int  main(void)
{
    void (*f)(void*);
    f = (*f)malloc(sizeof(f) * 2);
    f = printNr;
    (f  + 1) = printChar;
    (*f)(15);
    (*(f  + 1))('t');
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the error. I guess it is because you are not assigning to a pointer to pointer

Comment: Please provide a short sample program with the complete source code of what you are trying to do in your post. Also indicate what it is that you actually want to accomplish. You can create a variable that is then assigned a pointer to a function however you can not dynamically create a function, a lambda or a closure, and assign that to a variable in C.

Comment: You seem confused about the difference between *a pointer* and *what the pointer is pointing to*.   A function pointer points to a function. You can't dynamically allocate a function.

Comment: @Xtx  The sizeof operator may not be applied to a function. As result you may not declare an array of functions. For example a function definition can be unknown at compile time.

Comment: The compiler is complaining about `(*f)` before `malloc`. That is not a cast (and a cast is not needed anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to dynamically allocate space for an array of pointers to `int`s you need double ** (a pointer to pointer)

```
int **arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * n);
```

Same for an array of pointers to function, you need a double ** and then dereference to get the `sizeof`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fn1(void *val)
{
    puts((char *)val);
}

void fn2(void *val)
{
    puts((char *)val);
}

int main(void)
{
    void (**f)(void*);

    f = malloc(sizeof(*f) * 2);
    f[0] = fn1;
    f[1] = fn2;
    f[0]("Hello");
    f[1]("Bye");
    free(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To clarify -

1. it is illogical to alloc memory for the function, as you are not going to copy the code of the function there :)*1. You only assign the address of the memory where the function resides. Function is already in the memory.
2. You cant create the array of functions for the same reason as in point `1.` You can only create array of pointers to the functions.

*in the embedded development it sometimes used if function has to be run from RAM, RAM is limited, and it needs to freed for another one. But usually it is a static storage location instead of dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

There's all sorts of ill defined (if not actually undefined) behaviour in the two functions you've defined.  You're living dangerously (at best) with that code.  You could define the functions to take an `int` and then it would be OK (changing the function pointer type too).

However, I guess that's tangential to your immediate problem — the `(*f)` before `malloc()` is completely spurious.  If you want a cast there, you'd need `(void (**)(void *))` to specify a pointer to a pointer to a function returning `void` and taking a `void *` argument.

Here's fixed code with the type of function changed as suggested:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void printNr(int nr)
{
    printf("%i\n", nr);
}

static void printCh(int ch)
{
    printf("%c\n", ch);
}

int main(void)
{
    void (**f)(int);
    f = (void(**)(int))malloc(sizeof(*f) * 2);
    f[0] = printNr;
    f[1] = printCh;
    (*f)(15);
    (*(f  + 1))('t');
    free(f);
    return(0);
}
```

Note that the assignments (to `f[0]` and `f[1]`) were fixed too.  If you must use the non-array notation, then `*(f + 0)` and `*(f + 1)` would be self-consistent and `*f` and `*(f+1)` would also work.

It would be easier to use a typedef for the pointer to function type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void (*FunctionPtr)(int);

static void printNr(int nr)
{
    printf("%i\n", nr);
}

static void printCh(int ch)
{
    printf("%c\n", ch);
}

int main(void)
{
    FunctionPtr *f = (FunctionPtr *)malloc(sizeof(*f) * 2);
    f[0] = printNr;
    f[1] = printCh;
    (*f)(15);
    (*(f  + 1))('t');
    free(f);
    return(0);
}
```

Note that you can't use the typedef while defining the functions.  It's a curious quirk of C that you can't do that, even if you define a function type instead of a function pointer type.  For example, given `typedef void Function(int);`, you can't define `static Function printNr { … }` or anything similar and have it mean the same as the functions that are defined.  Trying `static Function *returnsPtr(int n) { … }` compiles (if the body is appropriate) but returns a function pointer (`Function *` or `FunctionPtr`).

The cast from `malloc()` isn't needed if you're using a C compiler.  If you're using a C++ compiler, it is needed.  The code (both programs) frees the allocated memory.  Neither program checks the allocation — slap wrist.